# How to create expression(of TDelegate) where delegate type is unknown at compile time?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda, expression

I have a code below to make collection that bind to a gridview able to sort by clicking on the column header. The problem here is "IPerson" is unknown at compile time. I want the delegate type able to decide by getting from gridview datasource.

```
Dim list As List(Of IPerson) = CType(Session("DataSource"), List(Of IPerson))
Dim dataType As Type = list.GetType.GetGenericArguments(0)
Dim param = Expression.Parameter(dataType, e.SortExpression)
Dim sortExpression = Expression.Lambda(
        Of Func(Of IPerson, Object))(
        expression.Convert(
            Expression.Property(param, e.SortExpression), GetType(Object)
            ), param)

GridView1.DataSource = list.AsQueryable.OrderBy(sortExpression)
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: So if `list` comes in typed as `object`, the only other place that you need `IPerson` is to pass as a type argument to `Expression.Lambda`, right? Some ugly-but-straightforward Reflection code should do the job...

Answer (score 0):

We had same problem when building custom ORM, that uses interfaces as entities. You can explore solution from this sources https://github.com/acropolium/AcroDB/tree/master/AcroDB/QueryableProxy